# How to test a Primefaces GeocodeEvent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using Primefaces 6.1.

I'm working with p:gMap like this

```
<p:gmap center="#{sellerController.centerGeoMap}"
                                                zoom="13" 
                                                type="MAP" 
                                                style="width:100%;height:300px" 
                                                id="geoGmap" 
                                                widgetVar="geoMap"
                                                binding="#{sellerController.geoMap}"
                                                model="#{sellerController.geoModel}"
                                                >
                                            <p:ajax event="geocode" listener="#{sellerController.onGeocode}" update="@this" />
                                        </p:gmap>
```

The application is working but I don't know how to test the method called with the ajax event "geocode", because when I try to create an instance of GeocodeEvent an IllegalArgumentException is raised because "source is null"

Here the method to test

```
public void onGeocode(GeocodeEvent event) {
...
...
}
```

And here a partial stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56)
    at javax.faces.event.FacesEvent.<init>(FacesEvent.java:72)
    at javax.faces.event.BehaviorEvent.<init>(BehaviorEvent.java:71)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.<init>(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:73)
    at org.primefaces.event.AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.<init>(AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.java:27)
    at org.primefaces.event.map.GeocodeEvent.<init>(GeocodeEvent.java:30)
```

How can I test this method?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use somethimg like  arquilian (and can you test other events of other compoments)

Comment: No, it's only a unit test.

Comment: Thanks, but there were actually two questions in my previous comment. What about the second one

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't see the question marks. For all the UIComponent I've the same problem.Now I'll try to mock the interface with Mockito and I'll let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys here the complete example, using Mockito. In fact was pretty obvious... :/

With Mockito you can mock the two parameters with the following

```
UIComponent mockUiComponent = Mockito.mock(UIComponent.class);
Behavior mockBehavior = Mockito.mock(Behavior.class);
```

And in my case the rest of the method is like the following:

```
sellerController.onGeocode(new GeocodeEvent(mockUiComponent,mockBehavior, "", null));
//Asserts for the case with null on last parameter

List<GeocodeResult> gResults = new ArrayList<>();
LatLng expectedLatLng = new LatLng(2d, 3d);
String expectedTitle = "via dei casari 1";
gResults.add(new GeocodeResult(expectedTitle, expectedLatLng));
gResults.add(new GeocodeResult("via dei casari 2",new LatLng(4d, 5d)));
gResults.add(new GeocodeResult("via dei casari 3",new LatLng(6d, 7d)));
sellerController.onGeocode(new GeocodeEvent(mockUiComponent,mockBehavior, "", gResults));
// Asserts for the case with a populated list
```

Hope to be useful